# Calculating the summation $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ika}}{1+|k|^r}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-transform

I want to calculate 
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ika}}{1+|k|^r}$$
for $r\geq 2$ and $r\in N$.
\begin{align*}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ika}}{1+|k|^r}&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ik\lambda}}{1+k^r}+\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{e^{ika}}{1+|k|^r}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ika}}{1+k^r}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ika}}{1+k^r}\\
&=1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ka)}{1+k^r}
\end{align*}

I don't know how to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ka)}{1+k^r}$.

Any help, even  for a specific $r$, is appreciated.

Comment: For $a=1$ and $r=2$ wolfram Alpha is returning a large mess for your last sum

Comment: XD sorry, I meant $a$, not $k$. I've deleted my silly mistake. However, I stand by the fact that finding a closed form for general $r$ might be wishful thinking

Comment: Got it. Thanks!